# SQL sums and divisions

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I am trying to calculate percentages of certain hours for students depending on campus locations.. So I am taking their total sum of hours for the semester and trying to divide it by the hours only taken from that campus to come up with a rough percentage home campus.

example if 80% of their classes occurred at campus A then I could use that. I changed the table names from what they are for obvious reasons

Here is what I have been trying and can't seem to make it work. Any Tips/Advice

```
select "credits_sum" / "div_hours"
from  table1
where credits_sum = (select sum(credit_hr)
             from table1
             where table1_term_code = 201480
             and table1_rsts_code not like 'D%'
             and table1_id = 1234)

and div_hours =  (select sum (credit_hr)
              from table1
              where table1_id = 1234
              and table1_TERM_CODE = 201480
              and table1_RSTS_CODE not like 'D%'
              and table1_RSTS_CODE not like 'W%'
              and table1_CAMP_CODE = 'PPE'
              and table1_CREDIT_HR > 0
              group by table1_id);
```

Comment: Please show sample table data.

Comment: I think SQL's analytic functions would solve the job in a more effective way.

Comment: `So I am taking their total sum of hours for the semester and trying to divide it by the hours only taken from that campus to come up with a rough percentage home campus.` - You have your numerator and denominator mixed up. It should be campus hours / total hours to get a percentage of hours on that campus.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use CASE statements to pull this off. What you are doing now with your `WHERE` clause is just restricting entire records based off of sums from other selections... and it doesn't make any sense.

I suspect what you want is something like:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN table1_term_code = 201480
            and table1_rsts_code not like 'D%'
             and table1_id = 1234 THEN credit_hr END)
        /
    SUM( CASE WHEN table1_id = 1234
              and table1_TERM_CODE = 201480
              and table1_RSTS_CODE not like 'D%'
              and table1_RSTS_CODE not like 'W%'
              and table1_CAMP_CODE = 'PPE'
              and table1_CREDIT_HR > 0 THEN credit_hr END) AS divisionField
from  table1
```

Comment: this works wonderful, David Faber in my comment above did realize I moved the numerator and denominator around wrong, but this code works! thank you